# Want to Drag and Drop Table loaded in Ajax into a Tab

Tags: ajax, tabs, html-table, drag-and-drop

On my Index.html page, many tabs. Into some of them, I load a table (grid) from an .asp file. It works fine. I want that table to be "drag and dropable". The .asp file works fine when run by itself, but doesn't into the tab. I make a sample .html file with a drag and dropable table (exact same structure as the result table of the asp file), it works... Why? :-)

Here is part of the code :

the html :

```
<table id="sort" class="grid" title="tout a moi" border="1">
```

the jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sort tbody").sortable().disableSelection();
        })
```

I remember once reading a solution somewhere but don't seem to find it again.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the helper. Like this, it works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
                    ui.children().each(function() {
                        $(this).width($(this).width());
                        });
            return ui;
            };

        $("#sort tbody").sortable({
                        helper: fixHelper
                        }).disableSelection();
        });
```